Why is 負ける here used transitively?
This is not the transitive 負ける that means "to reduce the price of a good".
During (sort of) mecha-fight, villain responds to hero who says that they will take the helm and fight and protect an injured woman on board:

怪我人を乗せていたのを負けた口実にされては堪らんからな
ガンメンでの借りはガンメンで返えさせてもらう ！
それが俺のやり方だ ！
I
wouldn't want you to say you lost because you had a wounded woman on
board.
An insult done to me by a Gunmen will be repaid in my Gunmen!
That's the way I do things! [show's translation]

I have difficulty with the first sentence. Why is 負ける used transitively? Don't you usually use に? The only way I take this sentence logically is like:

"It would be unbearable for you use the pretext of losing due to
having a injured person on board"

But this interpretation isn't coherent with the confusing structure of 怪我人を乗せていたのを負けた. What is going on here?

You are kind of parsing it wrong. It's 「怪我人を乗せていたのを」 + 「負けた口実にされて」, kind of '[dealing with you] making having an injured person on board into a pretext for having lost'
Were these subtitles from a fansub?

No they were official translation. I see where I was off now.
